# Service throwing "undefined method" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I may be missing something obvious, but I can't figure out where my problem is. I have a service called GoodMorning (app/services/good_morning.rb)

```
class GoodMorning

    def self.dawn(user)
        if user.goal_days.where("day = ?", Date.today).count == 0
            user.goals.each do |goal|
                if goal[time.strftime("%A")] == true
                    GoalDay.create(goal_id: goal.id, body: goal.body, target: goal.target, actual: 0, day: Date.today)
                end
            end
            session[:sun] = true
        end
    end
end
```

And then in a controller called Clearing (app/controllers/clearing_controller.rb) I call it:

```
def index
    @user = current_user
    @goals_today = GoalDay.where("user_id = ? AND day = ?", @user.id, Date.today)
    if session[:sun] == true
      if @goals_today.count == 0
        session[:sun] = false
      end
    else
      GoodMorning(@user).dawn
    end
end
```

I get the following error:

> undefined method `GoodMorning' for #

Thank you for any help seeing what I'm missing! I restarted the server etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
GoodMorning.dawn(@user)
```